# Why does std::vector::reserve call the copy constructor?

Tags: c++, gcc, vector, stl

Why does the following code not work with `g++` version 4.9.2? If I try to build it the compiler complains about the missing copy constructor in the line where the vector is told to reserve more memory.

```
#include <vector>

class Number
{
public:
    explicit Number(const int& i) : _value(i) {}

    Number(const Number& other) = delete;
    Number& operator=(const Number& other) = delete;

private:
    int _value;
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<Number> numbers;
    numbers.reserve(8);

    return 0;
}
```

Why would the compiler even try to call the deleted copy constructor when the storage size of the vector is increased? There are no objects inside the vector anyway.

Comment: Reserve will need to copy existing elements over if the capacity is increased.

Comment: I does not matter, whether the vector contains elements or not, a proper reserve has to consider possible existing elements. Hence the instantiation of the copy constructor (if memory gets reallocated)

Answer (score 14):

The short answer is because the language standard says so.  But that isn't interesting.

Reserve can call the copy constructor if there was data in the container.

Which branch of `reserve` it follows (no copy, or copy) is determined at run time, not compile time.

You are seeing a compile time error, not a run time error.  You have stated that no code that can possibly cause your object to copy should be compiled.

The compiler does not analyze the spot where `reserve` is, prove to itself the vector is empty, use that to determine which branch of code `reserve` will run, then say "no problem".  Instead, it compiles the function, which contains copies, and generates an error.

In theory, a container that allows pre-allocation (while empty) and emplace construction only (up to the pre-determined limit) would not require objects with any kind of copy or move construction.  At the time the `std` container library was written, emplace construction was impractical, so this option does not exist in the `std` container library: prior to C++11, the only way to put objects into a `vector` was to copy it.

`std::dynarray` comes close, but it doesn't let you have the buffer be half-unused and filled gradually.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you. I'm  not sure I fully understand it though. I wanted to test the new move semantics of `c++11` and later. Further code would have called `emplace_back` and such. Does your answer imply that even when only move semantics are used the object to be stored in the `vector` needs a copy constructor? What about `unique_ptr`? Even though it can't be copied it still needs a copy constructor just so it can be placed inside a `vector`?

Comment: @ifsch move would work fine, copy only needed by, well, vector copy.

Comment: Yakk is correct. As a side note, [`boost::container::vector`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/container/main_features.html) is similar to the standard vector but doesn't require copy constructability for reserving capacity.